# Rails ActionCable channel does unexpected extra unsubscribe and subscribe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable, hotwire-rails

I'm working on a feature that shows currently online users, on a specific page (called 'matter')

on top of `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= turbo_stream_from("matter_online_assessors", channel: MatterOnlineAssessorsChannel, data: { matter_id: @matter.id }) %>
```

channel:

```
class MatterOnlineAssessorsChannel < Turbo::StreamsChannel
  before_subscribe :set_matter
  before_unsubscribe :set_matter

  def subscribed
    super
    return unless current_user
    @matter.online_assessors << current_user.id 

    Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_append_to(
      verified_stream_name_from_params,
      target: 'matter_online_assessors',
      partial: 'assessors/matters/online_assessor',
      locals: { assessor: current_user }
    )
  end

  def unsubscribed
    return unless current_user
    @matter.online_assessors.remove(current_user.id) # redis list

    Turbo::StreamsChannel.broadcast_remove_to(
      verified_stream_name_from_params,
      target: ActionView::RecordIdentifier.dom_id(current_user)
    )
  end

  private
    def set_matter
      @matter = Matter.find(params[:matter_id])
    end
end
```

What happens:

- First time going to the show page:

  - I only get 1 subscribe event. All good
- **[BUG HERE]** Navigate away (1 unsubscribe event), and visit the show page again:

  - I get more than just 1 subscribe event: a subscribe -> unsubscribe -> subscribe (pic below)

[image]

What could cause this?

Comment: This is a long shot, but any chance your `turbo_stream_from` is inside a portion of the page that stays put (due to a turbo-frame) even when you navigated away?

Comment: I will double check, but I don't think so, because when navigating away, it does unsubscribe (will edit the post).

Comment: Is this in dev?  Any chance you’re using the async adapter?  That’s been buggy compared to using redis. Also a bit of a long shot with that though.

Comment: I'm using the redis adapter even in development